# Open a connection to a local DB asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm trying to open a connection to a DB and then insert a record into a table. At the moment it's just a simple localDB, I have looked at opening the connection with the sqlclient namespace methods.

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;
AttachDbFilename=C:\\FILE\\PATH\\EXAMPLE\\TechMVCDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True;
Connect Timeout=30");
```

I'm not certain that my connection string is even correct, I got it directly from the connection string box when you click on your database in the server explorer panel. I added a breakpoint in the code after the connection was opened and a select all statement was executed :

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\\FILE\\PATH\\EXAMPLE\\TechMVCDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand();
            com.Connection = con;
            com.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Table ORDER BY Id";
            SqlDataReader rdr = com.ExecuteReader();
```

I then get this error "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Table'.'" Table was just simply the name of the table was it also treating it as a keyword?

After this I changed the tablename to TechTester and ran it again, it ran with no errors and seemed to get the correct field amount of 4 id,sequence,direction,time it didn't seem to get the inserted test data.

I've also looked at using the Entity framework and implemented the very beginnings of it so I have my entity model class setup but nothing more. Is this the direction I should actually go with? How would I access the entity database?

My question is How do I best open a connection to a local db in asp.net-MVC using C#?

Comment: Whatever you use (Entity Framework or direct ADO.NET commands) you should store the connectionstring in the config file of your application. Do not hard code it inside your sources.

Comment: @Steve At the moment I'm just hardcoding whilst I test, does the connection string look correct?

Comment: Always add "Database=LogicalNameForYourDB" to avoid problems with AttachDbFileName (Trying to attach a database already attached or something like that) However if you want to use EF the connectionstring is a bit different See http://connectionstrings.com

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Oracle and SQL Server reserved keywords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16769799/oracle-and-sql-server-reserved-keywords)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Table` is one of the [SQL Server reserved keywords](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql).